# Data validation select multiple items error message from text entered in non drop down list cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to produce a code whereby the user can multiple items from a drop down menu (separated by a comma in the original cell) and then remove them by selecting the same item again.  This pertains to only one column, I in the workbook and the other columns are regular columns where the user will be entering in text.  I'm running into a problem in that the code that I have (see below) works on Column I but when the user tries to enter any information into other cells in other columns on the same worksheet, Run time error 1004 Application defined or object defined error pops up.  When I press debug, it highlights If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then.  I copied this code from Contextures Inc and experience the same problem when I click on an outside cell in their test spreadsheet.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Option Explicit
' Developed by Contextures Inc.
' www.contextures.com
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim strVal As String
Dim i As Long
Dim lCount As Long
Dim Ar As Variant

If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    newVal = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    oldVal = Target.Value
    Target.Value = newVal
    If Target.Column = 9 Then
        If oldVal = "" Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            If newVal = "" Then
                'do nothing
            Else
                On Error Resume Next
                Ar = Split(oldVal, ", ")
                strVal = ""
                For i = LBound(Ar) To UBound(Ar)
                    Debug.Print strVal
                    Debug.Print CStr(Ar(i))
                    If newVal = CStr(Ar(i)) Then
                        'do not include this item
                        strVal = strVal
                        lCount = 1
                    Else
                        strVal = strVal & CStr(Ar(i)) & ", "
                    End If
                Next i
                If lCount > 0 Then
                    Target.Value = Left(strVal, Len(strVal) - 2)
                Else
                    Target.Value = strVal & newVal
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines immediately before `If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler`:

```
Set Target  = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(9))
If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

This will restrict the range `Target` only to cells in Column 9

Then you can remove this test:

```
If Target.Column = 9 Then

End If
```